# How to detect SizeChanged event after using .HeightRequest

Tags: xamarin.forms

I noticed that after using the .HeightRequest property on a View in Xamarin.Forms that a method I have assigned to the SizeChanged event is no longer called.

The content within the View that had called .HeightRequest is a Label that contains text which can be zoomed in. When zooming in, the text now exceeds the "bounds" of the View's height, and the height is no longer adjusting as it once was.

```
        public ExpandableEntryView(...)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // my beautiful code

            SizeChanged += ExpandableEntryView_SizeChanged;
            UpdateUI();
        }

        private void ExpandableEntryView_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this is never called once .HeightRequest is assigned a value
        }

        private void SomeFunction() {

            sectionsStackLayout.HeightRequest = 0; // this causes SizeChanged to no longer work
        }
```

I essentially need this View to minimize its height to 0, and then return to its original height when I tell it to. I am also using IsVisible, but the Height property is required for an animation I am trying to do.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I was able to figure it out. The reason why the SizeChanged event is no longer called is because the view is no longer responsible for keeping track of its size after assigning a value to HeightRequest. So, if you would like for your View to return to being able to determine its own size once again, (i.e. if a child element in that View happens to change size/scale) you need to assign the HeightRequest to -1. This will then reenable the SizeChanged event.

Hope this helps somebody!